# Set focus to List item on Listview

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a Listview her ItemsSource property is binded to ViewModel, when i add a new item to List (ObservableCollection) i need set focus to the new item.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property of the ListView to a property in your ViewModel and when you add a new item to the collection set the property in your ViewModel to reference that new item and the binding will take care of the rest.

Comment: yes i know but other element outside from listview, i need change the not only the selecteditem i need that the listview get the focus